# Magento custom module with custom url with add .html extension

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.7, url-rewriting

I have created an module  and its front end name is test .
 Now i want a URL like

```
 www.exmpale.com/test/red.html (original structure is like 'test/index/index/valuid/1/').
 www.exmpale.com/test/green.html (original URL is like 'test/index/index/valueid/3/').
```

Wheremy crontroller is `indexCrontroller` and action is `indexAction` and where red /green ,will coming  dynamic from a table.
 The Table is structure is like

```
 tab_id  value
 1      red

 2      blue
 3      green
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the **Router** for these URLs. please follow this link

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

Use 301 redirect in htaccess file as follows:

Paste the below code in your .htaccess file in root folder:

`Redirect 301   /test/index/index/valuid/1/ www.exmpale.com/test/red.html`

`Redirect 301   /test/index/index/valuid/3/ www.exmpale.com/test/green.html`

Comment: Thanks for reply...but i cannot used it...A lot of records will be come from db... i want feature like  catalog url....