# Magento extension for Customize (product) URL

Tags: magento

Is there any extension to customize Magento (product) URL?

I want add some custom path in prosuct URL e.g. I want URL to look like mydomain.com/[mycustomword]/[sku]/product-url-key.html

Any body please suggest extension with dunction as above? Thanks

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952021/magento-custom-module-with-custom-url-with-add-html-extension

Comment: Thanks! I actually wanted to customize product URL (I edited my question)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in URL rewrite & custom URL rewrite functionality in Magento: http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/

Hope this helps.